# PHP get_category() function redeclared

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, categories, include

I'm not a developer, hence why i'm asking for the help of you experts :).

I was assigned the task to move a wordpress website (From apache with php 5.4.45 to IIS with PHP 5.6). Once migrated I'm getting the below error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_categories() (previously declared in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\category.php:26) in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\category.php on line 26
```

It's rather weird since it's saying that the get_categories function is re-declared in the same file / line in which it's declared. get_category() function in wp-includes/category.php follows:

```
function get_categories( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'category' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    $taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];

    /**
     * Filters the taxonomy used to retrieve terms when calling get_categories().
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     *
     * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy to retrieve terms from.
     * @param array  $args     An array of arguments. See get_terms().
     */
    $taxonomy = apply_filters( 'get_categories_taxonomy', $taxonomy, $args );

    // Back compat
    if ( isset($args['type']) && 'link' == $args['type'] ) {
        /* translators: 1: "type => link", 2: "taxonomy => link_category" alternative */
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '3.0.0',
            sprintf( __( '%1$s is deprecated. Use %2$s instead.' ),
                '<code>type => link</code>',
                '<code>taxonomy => link_category</code>'
            )
        );
        $taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'] = 'link_category';
    }

    $categories = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

    if ( is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = array();
    } else {
        $categories = (array) $categories;
        foreach ( array_keys( $categories ) as $k ) {
            _make_cat_compat( $categories[ $k ] );
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

Wordpress version is 4.7.5. Also tried re-installing wordpress from /wp-admin backend using the re-install function to no unveil. Following that we manually uploaded the wp-includes folder. All plugins and themese are up-to-date.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try _manually_ reinstalling the whole of WordPress (not just the `wp-includes` directory)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic That actually did solve the issue. Thanks for that. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. The weird thing, is that the error is not present in the old environment but is present in the new (Resolved through re-uploading wordpress).